# css code desktop view and mobile view is not working

Tags: html, css, iphone

What I want is the below:
[image: like this]

so I have the css code:

and html code is:

```
<body>
 <div class="contanier">

    <div id="rightcol">Right Section</div>
<div id="content">Content Section</div>

    </div>
</body>
```

I am following this site:

[desktop and mobile view](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes)

But I am getting like this:
[image: like this]

here the desktop view is ok..but I am not getting the mobile view ..In mobile view the content in not going below. where is the problem? what more I have to add?

with this code I am not getting the space.

but in this code the "rightcol" is not going down.

According to the suggestion..I am getting space between "container" and "right section",i.e:
[image]

Comment: your container was only set to 70% wide

Comment: yes but in the pereviously I was not getting that space..now its arrive

Comment: did you try the new fiddle? http://www.jsfiddle.net/24jjfkom/6

Comment: Yes...Now It is working perfectly..

Comment: hurrah! good teamwork :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Display your divs `inline-block` on desktop and `block` on mobile

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/24jjfkom/4/)

```css
        * {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  width: 100%;
  font-family: 'Cabin', sans-serif;
}
.contanier {
  margin:auto;
  height: 1500px;
  display: block;
  width: 70%;
   -webkit-flex: 3 1 60%;
           flex: 3 1 60%;
   -webkit-order: 2;
           order: 2;
}
#rightcol {
  background: #f00;
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
  width: 20%;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
  height: 500px;
   -webkit-flex: 1 6 20%;
           flex: 1 6 20%;
   -webkit-order: 3;
           order: 3;
}
#content {
  background: #fff;
  position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
 margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
  width: 59%;
  height: 500px;

   -webkit-flex: 1 6 20%;
           flex: 1 6 20%;
   -webkit-order: 3;
           order: 3;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
    #rightcol, #content{display:block!important; width:100%;}
    
   .contanier {
    -webkit-flex-flow: column;
            flex-direction: column;
   }

   #rightcol, #content {
    /* Return them to document order */
    -webkit-order: 0;
            order: 0;
   }

  #rightcol{
    min-height: 50px;
    max-height: 50px;
   }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="contanier">

    <div id="content">Content Section</div>

    <div id="rightcol">Right Section</div>
    

  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: BUt in your code the "right section is going to the left..and also it is not working in mobile.Please look at my question ,there is a picture what I want..

Comment: @preeti i swapped the divs a second ago. try again

Comment: it is working..But I am getting a space ..i am updating my question

Answer (score 0):

```
#rightcol {
     display: inline-block; /* alternative to float */
}
```

link here: http://learnlayout.com/inline-block.html